# get last word typed in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm wondering how to get the last word typed in Javascript. I have a text area `my_text` and when the user hits the `spacebar` it will get the last word that the user typed. This is what I'm trying so far

```
function getLastWord() {
        var input = document.getElementById(my_text.value);
        //var lineIn = document.getElementById(my_text).innerHTML;
        var lastWordTyped
        var changeColorOfWord;

        if (input == null) {
            input == " ";
        }

        lastWordTyped = input.substr(input.trim().lastIndexOf(" ") + 1);
```

When the function gets called on a spacebar hit, it says that `input` is `null` so when it gets the `lastWordTyped` var, it shows up null and errors out, does anybody know why this may be happening?

Preferably no JQuery

Here's some of the `HTML` to go with it.

```
<body>
<br />

<!-- Text area -->
<textarea class="text_edit" id="my_text" onkeypress="return myKeyPress(event)" onkeydown="return onKeyDown(event)"></textarea>
<br />

<!-- Submit button -->
<input type="button" value="Run Code" onclick="view_text()" />

<!-- Empty div to put the text in -->
<div id="view_text">
</div>
```

Ok, so I got the error to go away now i just need it to change the font color of the word typed lol..

Comment: your id selector seems like it might be incorrect...you're putting the value of the textfield where the ID should be. If you fix that it looks like your code should work okay...although it's not the way i'd probably do it

to be clear...I think it should be document.getElementById(my_text)

Comment: Can you provide a piece of HTML you use with your function?

Comment: Yes, the id selector is wrong; use getElementById("my_text")  --and later, use input.value to actually pull the text.  (On another issue, it is generally not wise to use something like "input" for a JavaScript variable name, when in the overall web page, it is an HTML keyword.  Some minor variant, like "inpt" can be useful enough without potentially confusing the browser.)

Comment: It's still not getting the text I have entered it's just getting the last button i pressed which is `" "` which is showing up null and causing it to error out.. :(

Comment: Can we see the code for that myKeyPress(event) function?  --also, the last line of code in getLastWord() is specifying input.substr(), but should specify input.value.substr()

Comment: @vernonner3voltazim Ok I fixed that error I didn't put `""` around `my_text`... But now it's saying that the `object has no method called trim`

Comment: Sorry for not saying this sooner.  I didn't because that first Answer below indicates using ".value" differently from the way you did in your original use of the getElementByID() function.  If you copied that Answer, your "no method" error should go away.  If you didn't copy it, but only did what I suggested in my first comment above, then you should, everywhere you specify the "input" variable, specify "input.value" to reference the string.  That includes the line where you are calling "trim()" and getting an error.

Answer (score 3):

Did you mean

```
var input = document.getElementById("my_text").value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<textarea id="MyText" rows="10" cols="50" onkeyup="getLastWord(event);"></textarea>


var Old = "";
var New = ""; 
function getLastWord(e)
{
    New = document.getElementById("MyText").value;
    if(e.keyCode == 32)
    {
        Old = New.replace(Old, "");
        alert(Old);
        Old = New;
    }
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ue5k08q6/2/)**

Comment: This does not accomplish what the OP has asked